# How to read JSON array data from URL

Tags: c#, arrays, json

```
[{'Name':'John Smith','Age':34},{'Name':'shankar','Age':24}]
```

My JSON array url data look like above code.Now i wanted to read it in c#. I have written following code for recieve data.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string json;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
   json = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();           
var persons = serializer.Deserialize<List<Person>>(json);

foreach (var item in persons)
{
   //Console.Write("Name:" + item.name + " and Age: " + item.age);
}

public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

But i am getting sone html code in json variable and getting Invalid JSON primitive: error message.What is the process to read json array data in c#.

Comment: If you get html in the response, its not json. Check the source data and make sure its ONLY json, visit the path you request and check source, make sure its ONLY json data, and nothing more.
Do you have control over the API that you fetch json from?

Comment: Please give us the contents of your json variable after finishing the stream reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

Comment: Hes using the `JavascriptSerializer` class (System.Web) you'r example requires Json.net (Newtonsoft) (which i personally would recommend) the one heuses should work if the data is formated right. :P